# maxpooling2d keras does not do pooling at all

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I am writing a CNN for text classification. The max pooling2D layer seems does not work as the output shape is same as conv2D. I have attached my code and output shape below. Thanks for helping me!

```
    from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Flatten
    from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Embedding, Reshape, Concatenate, Dropout
    from keras import optimizers
    from keras.models import Model

    convs = []
    filter_sizes = [2,4,8]
    BATCH_SIZE = 10

    sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
    reshape = Reshape((MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, EMBEDDING_DIM,1))(embedded_sequences)

    conv_0 = Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, filter_sizes[0]), activation='relu')(reshape)
    conv_1 = Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, filter_sizes[1]), activation='relu')(reshape)
    conv_2 = Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, filter_sizes[2]), activation='relu')(reshape)

    maxpool_0 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH - filter_sizes[0] + 1,1), strides=(1,1), padding='same')(conv_0)
    maxpool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH - filter_sizes[1] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='same')(conv_1)
    maxpool_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH - filter_sizes[2] + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='same')(conv_2)

    concatenated_tensor = Concatenate(axis = 2)([maxpool_0, maxpool_1, maxpool_2])
    flatten = Flatten()(concatenated_tensor)
    dense = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(flatten)
    dense_out = Dropout(0.5)(dense)
    preds = Dense(label_dim, activation='sigmoid')(dense_out)

    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=opt,
          metrics=['acc'])
```

[output shape for each layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUuqV.png)

Comment: Why are you putting padding=same in your MaxPooling layers?

Comment: @ Matias Valdenegro Because I want the outputs for three different filters size to be the same.

Comment: I don't understand then, you say pooling doesn't work because shapes are the same, but you forced this with the use of padding.

Comment: @ Matias Valdenegro I made a mistake on stride, it should be the same as kernel_size in pooling. If you can see from the output shape, I got (None, 1, 199, 128) for first filter size after conv2D, I should got (None, 1, 1, 128) for first filter size after maxpooling2D, however, it returns (None, 1, 199, 128), which is exactly the same as conv2D. I am not sure what happened, why max pooling does not work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: MaxPooling is working as intended, the problem is your understanding of what the parameters do. I wouldn't use padding=same with pooling as the whole purpose of using pooling is to reduce dimensions (the shapes).

Comment: I don't quite understand. The parameter padding is just whether or not add paddings while pooling. In my situation, no matter what type of padding I selected, it should return (None, 1, 1, 128) after pooling. But the program returns  (None, 1, 199, 128), which is wired.  By the way,  I tried padding = same and padding = valid, both of them does not work.

Comment: Seems what you want is GlobalMaxPooling2D, that one will collapse spatial dims to one.